# How to use Hibernate criteria without joining the sub-classes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

I'm trying to use Hibernate criteria without joining the sub-classes. Here is my case:

Notification.hbm.xml has the relation:

```
<many-to-one name="myObject" class="MyObject" column="MY_OBJECT_UID" not-null="true" index="NOTIFICATIONS_OBJECT" foreign-key="NOTIFICATIONS_OBJECT"/>
```

my JAVA code:

```
1. Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Notification.class.getName());
2. criteria.createAlias("myObject", "myObject", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
3. criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("myObject.name").ignoreCase());
4. List<Notification> res = (List<Notification>) criteria.list();
```

If i remove lines 2 and 3 i get the result without joining MyObject, but if i add them, then the query is massive and doing Join with all of MyObject sub classes (and there are many).

I need a solution to avoid those Hibernate joins. One join for MyObject is OK (although not necessary), but Join to every subClass of it, is bad.
What are my option here? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to review your hibernate configuration. You need to specify the attribute "fetch" for say to hibernate how join all object. try to search on GOOGLE fetch="join" and fetch="select". If you need help post the configuration and explain what you want to do.

Comment: Another thing is that you can use session.createCriteria(Notification.class); instead of session.createCriteria(Notification.class.getName());

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I tried to add fetch="select" to the relation but without success.

Comment: I need to see the configurations and the entity code. In this way I cannot understand the structure of the DB.

Comment: <hibernate-mapping package="...."> 
 <class name="Notification" table="NOTIFICATIONS">
  <property name=....>
  <property name=....>
  <many-to-one name="myObject" class="MyObject" column="MY_OBJECT_UID" not-null="true" index="NOTIFICATIONS_OBJECT" foreign-key="NOTIFICATIONS_OBJECT"/>
 </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

    <hibernate-mapping package="....">
 <class name="MyObject" table="My_OBJECTS">
  <property name=....>
  .....
  <property name=....>
  <joined-subclass name="A" table="A">
  ...........
  </joined-subclass>
  .......
 </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

Comment: Please!!.... add it in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use projection, to query only the field you need

```
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("property1").as( "property1"));
...
criteria.setProjection(properties);

criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Notification.class));
```

You can map it, to you domain Object but its is better to map it to custom DTO like a NotificationDTO, because it won't be managed entity but simple pojo:

You won't be able to update/ delete it. But if you need the data in "read only" mode its the best solution.

Comment: Interesting. but how can i use it to get the whole object of 'notification', only that its property 'object' will return only the property name.
`notification->propery1 notification->propery2 notification->object (here all will be null besides the object name)`